# distinct values from multiple fields within one table ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I get distinct values from multiple fields within one table with just one request.

**Option 1**

```
SELECT WM_CONCAT(DISTINCT(FIELD1)) FIELD1S,WM_CONCAT(DISTINCT(FIELD2)) FIELD2S,..FIELD10S
  FROM TABLE;
```

WM_CONCAT is LIMITED

**Option 2**

```
select DISTINCT(FIELD1) FIELDVALUE, 'FIELD1' FIELDNAME
       FROM TABLE
UNION
select DISTINCT(FIELD2) FIELDVALUE, 'FIELD2' FIELDNAME
       FROM TABLE
... FIELD 10
```

is just too slow

Comment: So you are trying to concatenate the output of a select query to a single record, aren't you? something like this? http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:229614022562

Comment: How slow is "too slow"?  How many records are we talking about?  How many distinct values out of how many total records?

Comment: @APC Option 2 is about 80 seconds, it goes through 108443 records

Comment: @Jai No, The format isn't important, I just it want it to be fast as possible

Comment: so is needed one full scan, not 10.

Comment: I would like to see some more context in this question.  What are you trying to achieve?  To get all distinct values from all fields in the table, irrespective of which column they are in or any other semantics?  That doesn't sound terribly useful, really.  Tell us what you are trying to do and why, and you will probably get better answers!

Answer (score 2):

if you were scanning a small range in the data (not full scanning the whole table) you could use `WITH` to optimise your query
e.g:

```
WITH a AS 
(SELECT field1,field2,field3..... FROM TABLE WHERE condition)
SELECT field1 FROM a
UNION   
SELECT field2 FROM a
UNION   
SELECT field3 FROM a
.....etc
```

Answer (score 2):

For my problem, I had

```
WL1   ...   WL2   ...  correlation
A            B             0.8
B            A             0.8
A            C             0.9
C            A             0.9
```

how to eliminate the symmetry from this table?

```
    select WL1, WL2,correlation from
    table
    where least(WL1,WL2)||greatest(WL1,WL2) = WL1||WL2
    order by WL1
```

this gives

```
WL1   ...   WL2   ...  correlation
A            B             0.8
A            C             0.9
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

The best option in the SQL is the `UNION`, though you may be able to save some performance by taking out the `distinct` keywords:

```
select FIELD1 FROM TABLE
UNION
select FIELD2 FROM TABLE
```

`UNION` provides the unique set from two tables, so distinct is redundant in this case. There simply isn't any way to write this query differently to make it perform faster. There's no magic formula that makes searching 200,000+ rows faster. It's got to search every row of the table twice and sort for uniqueness, which is exactly what `UNION` will do.

The only way you can make it faster is to create separate indexes on the two fields (maybe) or pare down the set of data that you're searching across.

Alternatively, if you're doing this a lot and adding new fields rarely, you could use a materialized view to store the result and only refresh it periodically.

Incidentally, your second query doesn't appear to do what you want it to. `Distinct` always applies to all of the columns in the `select` section, so your constants with the field names will cause the query to always return separate rows for the two columns.

---

I've come up with another method that, experimentally, seems to be a little faster. In affect, this allows us to trade one full-table scan for a Cartesian join. In most cases, I would still opt to use the `union` as it's much more obvious what the query is doing.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE lvl WHEN 1 THEN field1 ELSE field2 END
FROM              table
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT     LEVEL lvl
                   FROM       DUAL
                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2);
```

It's also worthwhile to add that I tested both queries on a table without useful indexes containing 800,000 rows and it took roughly 45 seconds (returning 145,000 rows). However, most of that time was spent actually fetching the records, not running the query (the query took 3-7 seconds). If you're getting a sizable number of rows back, it may simply be the number of rows that is causing the performance issue you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

When you get distinct values from multiple columns, then it won't return a data table. If you think following data

```
Column A            Column B

10                  50

30                  50

10                  50
```

when you get the distinct it will be 2 rows from first column and 1 rows from 2nd column. It simply won't work.

Answer (score 0):

And something like this?

```
SELECT 'FIELD1',FIELD1, 'FIELD2',FIELD2,...
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY FIELD1,FIELD2,...
```