# Get one list from two table columns

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have two tables in SQL Server which have two similar columns.

```
 table1 (
     partID, PartName,  ....
 )

 table2 (
    sekId,  Part2Name, ....
 )
```

I need to populate one combobox in vb.net with the cummulated values of `PartName` and `Part2Name` so that the list can appear like being sourced from one single column, because the user might require from either. The combobox must be one that's how the design has it. Is there an SQL statement to sort me out?

Comment: You can refer this article for reference :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789010/distinct-values-from-multiple-fields-within-one-table-oracle-sql

Answer (score 1):

U get all valuel like this:

```
SELECT PartName FROM table1
UNION
SELECT PartName From table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [UNION T-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) statement will join the two tables togheter

```
SELECT partID as IDNumber, PartName as Name FROM table1 
UNION 
SELECT sekID as IDNumber, Part2Name as Name From table2 
ORDER BY Name
```

and sort the union using the renamed column